# Maximal group image

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

How does one prove: if $S$ is a finitely generated Clifford semigroup its maximal group image is actually $S_{e_{n}}$?

Comment: Finitely generated semilattices are finite. So if you look at the structure semilattice of S then since S is finitely generated, it contains only finitely many idempotents, and hence has a minimal idempotent (which is just the product of all the idempotents).

Comment: And multiplication by that minimal idempotent, which is central, is a homomorphism to the maximal subgroup at that idempotent which is easily checked to be the maximal group image.

Comment: Alternatively, the maximal group image of a clifford inverse semigroup is the direct limit of the maximal subgroups (viewed as a directed system of groups indexed by the idempotents). In the finitely generated case the semilattice is finite so the system has a minimal element which is then the direct limit.

Comment: Strong semilattice of good equals clifford semigroup

Comment: you don't need a reference. In a semilattice the image of a word depends only on its set of letters.

Comment: Dear Lola, please find a copy of Howie's book or a similar source. If one wants to prove theorems about semigroups one should be prepared to learn some things about them

Comment: Since the idempotents commute in an inverse semigroup any semilattice of groups is strong.

Comment: If e is a minimal idempotent then eS is the maximal subgroup and s maps to es is a retraction to S.

Answer (score 2):

Let me expand on my earlier comments.

Firstly: it is an elementary exercise to prove that if $L$ is a semilattice and $x_1,\dots, x_n$ generate it as a semigroup, then $|L| \leq 2^n-1$.

Secondly: in general, a finitely generated semigroup can contain infinitely many idempotents (my apologies if I implied otherwise). A standard counterexample is the bicyclic monoid $\langle 1, p, q \mid qp=1\rangle$ which has two generators as a semigroup, but has infinitely many idempotents, namely the elements $p^nq^n$ for $n\geq 0$.

Finally, let me address your original question. (The question seems slightly basic, but perhaps it appears more complicated if one is unfamiliar with semigroup theory. A good place to learn the basics is Howie's *An Introduction To Semigroup Theory*.)

- Let $S$ be a semilattice of semigroups, say $S=\coprod_{e\in L} S_e$. This means that each $S_e$ is a subsemigroup of $S$ and $S_eS_f\subseteq S_{ef}$ for all $e,f\in L$.
- Let $\phi: S\to L$ be the unique function satisfying $x\in S_{\phi(x)}$ for all $x\in S$, i.e. $\phi$ tells you which piece of the grading you belong to. Note that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, i.e. $\phi$ is a homomorphism
- Suppose $S$ is finitely generated as a semigroup. Then, since $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism, it follows that $L$ is finitely generated a semigroup. Now we apply the first remark at the start of my answer.
- In particular, since every Clifford semigroup is a semilattice of groups (this is either a definition, or Theorem III.2.1 in Howie's book, depending on one's conventions) we get an answer to your original question.

Comment: It is extremely unwise to use notation like $xx^{-1}$ when you are not in a group. I think what I wrote is correct. Please look up the relevant definitions

Comment: In particular, I don't think one requires a strong semilattice. Note that if $S$ is not a strong semilattice then there is no reason to suppose we can emebed $L$ as a subsemigroup of $S$. Rather, $L$ is a quotient of $S$.